# Maximum Upload size?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss, sharepoint-2007

The Maximum Upload size is '50MB' for a web-application, will it be the same for the site-collections underneath of that web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the setting is for a Web Application, and a Site Collection is part of a Web Application.

Reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288157.aspx